# How do I give an input to my xpath output

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I need to insert commas to the list of outputs of my xpath.
This is my xpath:

```
//OrderLine/Product/*/ProductName
```

and this is the output:

```
Node ProductName : Email Service
Node ProductName : Email
Node ProductName : Internet Access Service
Node ProductName : IC31
Node ProductName : IC01
Node ProductName : Sport1 pakket
```

Desired Output:

```
Email Service, Email, Internet Access Service, IC31, IC01, Sport1 pakket
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [`string-join()`](https://maxtoroq.github.io/xpath-ref/fn/string-join.html) function as below:

```
string-join(//OrderLine/Product/*/ProductName, ",")
```

P.S. Available from XPath 2.0